# MSSQL replace issue

Tags: sql-server, replace

I am using a query like below:

`SELECT name, replace(name,'ş','s') FROM [EM_Last].[dbo].[EM_Asset] where id_asset = 4247`

The result is:

```
name         | (No column name)
işler güçler | işler güçler
```

Why replace doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I find the isue. Change query like below :

```
SELECT name, replace(name, N'ş','s') FROM [EM_Last].[dbo].[EM_Asset] where id_asset = 4247
```

it is work correctlly.